# Cannot launch GitHub pages repository as number of forks is -1?

Tags: git, github, fork, github-pages, git-fork

I was trying to deploy my personal website using GitHub Pages. However, when I created the repository using my username; sudoyolo.github.io, the repository is initialized with -1 number of forks.
[Number of forks is -1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqbJI.jpg)

I had previously forked my my repo from [academicpages.github.io](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io), but later decided to use another theme. So I deleted the forked repo and created a new repo with the same name (sudoyolo.github.io).
My working tree is clean and the new repo does not link with the old repo in terms of commit history (I used `git log`). Yet there the repo shows the number of forks as -1, and is not allowing me to launch GitHub pages as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be the issue with their service (however the status is OK), as I’m having exactly the same problem today. But I tried to create a separate repository to test, same issue, failed to deploy.